# Change slackbot startup messages

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api, chatbot

I am developing a slackbot, using [Simple slack Api](https://github.com/Ullink/simple-slack-api). My problem is, when a new user gets added to slack, slack shows slackbot at startup.
Is there a way, new users get redirected to my custom bot  on startup?

The reason i want to do that is, i want to provide instructions on how to use the custom bot on new user addition.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can switch to a custom bot. However, you can display information in the "slackbot" channel by simple sending a direct message to the user ID with your app / bot via API with [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage). Thus adding all the information you need to show new users.

Example:

```
https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=TOKEN&channel=U12345678&text=hallo
```

This example will produce a message "Hallo" in the slackbot channel of the user with the user ID U12345678 coming from an app. If this is using the token from a Slack app, that app will appear as sender.

Comment: I did not get you? If i send a message as my xyz user, it will still open the slackbot chatbox in the beginning right? Although my DM would be showing up as unread on the left pane.

Comment: I added more info. Hope that clarifies it.